# Custom fields table rate Magento 2

Tags: shipping, shipping-methods, luma-theme, magento-2.1.7

Hi i would need a custom table rate for Magento 2. The CSV file should be with these fields (Country, Region/State, ZIP/PostalCode, ProductSKU, ShippingPrice). Is there a way to do it without buying a module? In the attached file there is an example of what i need.

[image]

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: @PratikKamani Hi, I have found a solution using a free module. This module allow me to give for every product a different shipping price.

Comment: I code this in magento 2. In fact this takes much time to do. If you need then let me know. I can share git push link. according you can set.

Comment: @PratikKamni No thanks. I'm fine with the module, now I have problems with this: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/202947/how-to-call-phtml-file-in-static-block-magento-2