# How to call phtml file in static block - Magento 2

Tags: magento2, phtml, static-block, luma-theme

I created a file in phtml and would like to call it in a static block.

I created the cms folder inside the theme.

**My route is different and is not a duplicate**

**/public_html/app/design/frontend/Magento/luma/cms/file.phtml**

**How can I recall this file in a static block?**

Thanks

Comment: Is not a duplicate my route is different

Comment: Is not a duplicate my route is different. Please I tried with the other gruff but it did not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create custom module with an Block
In folder Custom_Module_Folder/view/frontend/view/test.phtml

And in your block you update the layout

```
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="YOUR BLOCK CLASS"
         name="test"
         template="test.phtml" after="-" 
        />
    </referenceContainer>
```

Comment: Does not work. I created /public_html/app/design/frontend/Magento/luma/Magento_Cms/templates/cms/file.php

and in the static block I entered {{block type = "core / template" template = "Magento_Cms: cms / file.phtml"}}

but nothing.

Comment: You can see in your logs? are you sure that you use Magento/luma as theme?

Comment: How can i see the logs?
However, I use Luma as a theme with some modifications made by me. My site is http://www.avalonitalia.com/

Comment: Log is in var/log/exception.log and  var/log/system.log but you must remove them and test for generate a new logs

Comment: I generate a new logs but is log. 
How can I do?

Comment: Its not clear post your log here for see how is the problem, search in log something about file.phtml

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69181/discussion-between-alessandro-and-mohamed-el-mrabet).